# Combining overlapping or consecutive date values with match_recognize

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm having difficulty getting the correct answer when trying to use match_recognise to combine or merge overlapping date values. The examples in the following link explain what I'm trying to do, but with my data is falling short in some circumstances:

https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/tutorial_E4DB2E0Z0D5ZTUBGN6JWUPKAU.html

Basically I have a set of data with date values that will sometimes overlap one another. There is no limit to how many date ranges could overlap, and there are a few variations I will see in the dates:

In summary these are the main variations:

1. Only a singular instance of dates, so would return as a single row (e.g. strt/a from the classifier)
2. Dates that overlap one another in sequence
3. Dates that overlap one another, but also has a singular set of dates that is greater than all the others

Here's an example:

Date ranges:

| Start | End |
| --- | --- |
| **26-AUG-16 13:14:00** | 19-OCT-16 15:38:31 |
| 26-AUG-16 13:14:03 | **01-NOV-16 19:14:51** |
| 26-AUG-16 13:15:01 | 19-OCT-16 15:39:11 |
| 21-OCT-16 15:38:03 | 24-OCT-16 06:01:35 |
| 24-OCT-16 14:26:02 | 31-OCT-16 14:14:53 |

Using a slightly modified version of the code from the link above:

```
select *
  from periods
match_recognize(
   order by end_date, start_date
   measures
      first(start_date) start_date, last(end_date) end_date
    , count(*) periods
    , match_number() match_no
    , classifier() class
   one row per match
   pattern( a b* )
   define
      b as start_date <= prev(end_date)
)
```

And I get the following:

| START_DATE | END_DATE | PERIODS | MATCH_NO | CLASS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **26-AUG-16 13:14:00** | 19-OCT-16 15:39:11 | 2 | 3 | B |
| 21-OCT-16 15:38:03 | 24-OCT-16 06:01:35 | 1 | 4 | A |
| 24-OCT-16 14:26:02 | **01-NOV-16 19:14:51** | 2 | 5 | B |

Where I'd expect to return the min start date of 26-Aug-2016, and max end date of 01-Nov-2016 as a single row to express the minimum/maximum start and end dates.

In playing with the code, I can find a way for it to work in this example, but it in-turn breaks other examples. So I *think* I'm needing to define more patterns for it to look for, but having difficulty getting it to work how I want and understanding the patterns I need to define.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: `Match recognize` may not be the only solution to this problem.  However, you have not clearly explained what you are trying to do and are insisting on using that functionality.

Comment: 19-OCT-16 does not overlap 01-NOV-16 (well, 2016 does overlap 1916 - but your date format is not clear). What do you expect as result?

Comment: Sorry, yes I appreciate match_recognise is not the only way to do this. I'm open to other suggestions, I just figured it should be possible with this approach is all.

In relation to what I'm trying to do, I'm trying to merge or combine dates that overlap in the same space and time to effectively get the min start date and the max end date.

Comment: I realised I made a mistake in the original post re what my expected output was, I've hopefully clarified that a little?

Comment: The solution you show is wrong - not because the code is wrong (I didn't check it, but I assume it is correct), but because it implements an incorrect algorithm, reflected in the `define` clause (together with the `pattern` clause). I explained this to Stew Ashton - he had come up with the same approach on his blog. I provided a counter-example there. He then posted a correct `match_recognize` solution (same link, under "the preferred solution"). Link: https://stewashton.wordpress.com/2015/06/10/merging-overlapping-date-ranges-with-match_recognize/

Comment: At some point you may also want to handle intervals with indeterminate start or end. You may use dates like `0001-01-01 00:00:00` and `9999-12-31 23:59:59` as markers, or (as I prefer) `null` to mark "minus infinity" for start_date or "plus infinity" for end date. You may be interested in this discussion on the Oracle developers community: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4177878/handling-nulls-in-interval-algebra

Comment: @GordonLinoff - there are solutions using analytic functions; they may be of interest to users of databases other than Oracle, since `match_recognize` is proprietary to Oracle. However, the (correct) `match_recognize` solution is more efficient (faster and easier on resources). Whether that is important in the OP's case, only the OP knows.

Comment: @Scottland - actually, looking at your current code, it's not quite the same as Stew Ashton's incorrect solution. That solution (his) was making a more subtle mistake; the mistake in your solution is much more basic. Best to read his blog post (and references in it to earlier posts on the same blog, where he shows the analytic functions solution too).

Comment: @mathguy - Match_recognize is not proprietary to Oracle; it is part of ANSI-2016 SQL standard. It does appear however that Oracle is the only implementer and it may very well have begun life as Oracle proprietary.

Comment: @mathguy - Re-read the blog, including the preferred solution I've had a go at and I'm getting a much better set of results now. So it does appear to fit what I want it for. So thanks for the headsup!